# C: "zsh: abort" error

Tags: c, arrays, strcat

Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
    int i;
    int k;

    i = 0;
    k = 0;
    while (dest[i])
        i++;
    while (src[k])
    {
        dest[i + k] = src[k];
        //i++;
        k++;
    }
    dest[i + k] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

int main(){
    //ft_strcat
    char str[] = "Hello, ";
    char str2[] = "World!";
    printf("%s", ft_strcat(str, str2));
    return 0;
}
```

It's implementing of strcat function.
When I'm trying to copy "World!" to "Hello, " I have an error "zsh: abort". There's no problem when I'm trying to copy to "Hello ".

What can I do with this error? Why this comma causes this problem?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Learn to [use](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: You can use `valgrind` to see memory errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define an array with empty dimension and initialize that with a brace-enclosed initializer list, the size of the array is determined by the supplied initializer list elements.

So, in your case, `str` and `str2` are **just** long enough to hold the *strings* `"Hello, "` and `"World!"`, respectively.

So, the problem here is, the destination buffer (passed as the first argument of `ft_strcat()`) has absolutely no space to hold the *concatenated* result. You're accessing out of bound memory, thus causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In the very first iteration of the `while` loop,

```
while (src[k])
    {
        dest[i + k] = src[k];
        //i++;
        k++;
    }
```

the index `i+k` points to out of bound memory for `dest`. No sooner than you try to use the index to access the memory location, you face UB.

You need to make sure, the destination has enough space left to hold the concatenated result. For that, you can have either of two approaches

- Define a bigger array size statically and use that as destination. You can always check for the actual size vs. already used size easily in this case, as this is a character type array meant to be used as *string* (*hint: `sizeof` vs `strlen()`*).
- You can make use of a pointer, use memory allocator function to allocate certain amount of memory and `realloc()` as needed.